# Where can I ask questions that need conceptual and non-technical reflections?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions, site-recommendation

I'd like to know is there is a place where we can ask questions about tools and software development, which are not really or not fully technical, but rather more conceptual or helping on higher-level aspects?

For example, if one wants to design a pattern or a piece of workflow. Or where to search for focused help to start a complex project. Or, in a more recent case, I was confronted with an old question to which I could never find an answer; at which point should I change my scripts and functions style program to a fully object oriented piece of code.

I already followed some introduction courses a long time ago. It was about objects, mentally defined as cars, cats and dogs or usual common stuff, but which you almost never face up in real tasks, or accessors and mutators which seems a totally overkill for my daily routines. Etc.

I never dared asking such questions on the main site because I always thought they would be off-topic, and they would probably be here too unfortunately, but any nice structured answer or point to existing discussion about that would be all what I need.

Comment: [softwareengineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) is a possibility for *some* questions somewhat similar to yours, though posts there still need to be reasonably focused and not too opinion-based.

Comment: @CertainPerformance is correct. Make sure to check their help section for what's on-topic and what isn't. So, follow that and makes sure the question is well formatted, focused, and answerable, too. Asking "how can I make X" doesn't fly neither on SO nor on SoftEng. A better question would be something like "I want to make X. I have design Y in mind (ideally diagrams and description). I'm interested in part Z of it (explain why)".

Comment: Note that you should be prepared for the possibility that your question is just not a good fit on any Stack Exchange site. There are other technical Q&A sites on the world wide web that you can avail yourself of. I'm not saying that's the case here (we have only a vague idea of what question you want to ask), but just wanted to throw that out there as food for thought.

Comment: [On Quora there](https://www.quora.com/Can-Python-be-used-to-develop-large-complex-enterprise-projects-so-that-the-core-functionality-and-behavior-of-the-software-is-written-solely-in-Python) [aren't any](https://www.quora.com/What-is-project-management-1) [limits wrt.](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-practices-in-scoping-software-development-projects) [broadness](https://www.quora.com/Which-are-the-best-tools-you-use-to-manage-software-development-projects).